# Reversing a line

Tags: c

I was trying to reverse a string (K&R) but when i try to use printf in main it outputs nothing but when
i try to use printf in reverse function and it works.Its confusing why prints takes place in reverse function but not in main function.can anybody help me on this??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
void reverse(char*);
int getlen(char*,int);
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    printf("\nEnter anything\n");
    while((getlen(line,MAXLINE))>1)
    {
        reverse(line);
    }
   printf("%s",line);//problem here
}
int getlen(char line[],int len)
{
    int c,i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n' && (i<(len-2)))//last two for \n and \0
    {
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    if(c=='\n')
        {
            line[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }

    line[i]='\0';
    return(i);//returns 1 if nothing is written
}
void reverse(char line[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    char temp;
    while(line[i]!='\0')
    ++i;
    --i;
    if(line[i]=='\n')
    --i;
    while(j<i)
    {
        temp=line[j];
        line[j]=line[i];
        line[i]=temp;
        ++j;
        --i;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have compiler warning on?

Comment: ++i;
    --i; what is this?

Comment: @Boltz0r note the missing braces....

Comment: Should you not be printing the line *inside* the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468568/help-with-reversing-a-string-in-c), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409964/reversing-a-string-in-c-does-not-output-the-reversed-line) and few more?

Comment: ++i increments i upto '\0',the after while loop breaks --i decrements i by 1 so its not in null position. @Boltz0r

Comment: This would be one of many reasons why the K&R book is bad. People reading it tend to end up writing obfuscated code.

Comment: well the question said to print the lines in reverse after all i/p taken @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Check the logic of the `getlen` function again, what it returns and what the contents of the array is when entering an empty line. And then check the logic of the loop condition, when will the loop exit, and what will the contents of `line` be then? Will the `reverse` function be called if `getlne` e.g. returns `1`? Where do you store the results of all the previous calls to `reverse`?

Comment: `reverse()` is broke

Answer (score 0):

> Print inside the loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
void reverse(char*);
int getlen(char*,int);
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    printf("\nEnter anything\n");
    while((getlen(line,MAXLINE))>1)
    {
        printf("%s",line);//problem here
        reverse(line);
        printf("%s",line);//problem here
    }

}
int getlen(char line[],int len)
{
    int c,i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n' && (i<(len-2)))//last two for \n and \0
    {
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    if(c=='\n')
        {
            line[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }

    line[i]='\0';
    return(i);//returns 1 if nothing is written
}
void reverse(char line[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    char temp;
    while(line[i]!='\0')
    ++i;
    --i;
    if(line[i]=='\n')
    --i;
    while(j<i)
    {
        temp=line[j];
        line[j]=line[i];
        line[i]=temp;
        ++j;
        --i;

    }

}
```

**Test**

```
$ gcc main.c 
$ ./a.out 

Enter anything
backwards
backwards
sdrawkcab
```

You can also try it [online](http://ideone.com/55kLBT) The code reverses a string with very small modifications to your code.

Comment: That is the problem i don't understand,why inside the loop why it doesn't work ourside,i mean i am calling an array isn't???

Comment: @Bazooka47 Please follow this link http://ideone.com/55kLBT Does it help? The code reverses a string with very small modifications to your code.

Comment: what i don't understand is if i am calling a variable by reference then shouldn't it print same if it was outside the loop???

Comment: @Bazooka47 I think that the string is "consumed" if you know what that means? The string changes every iteration.

Comment: @Bazooka47: C does not support call by reference! It is **stricly** call by value.